# Compute Inverse of Matrix with given pivoted LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

It has been some time since I listened to the lectures about linear algebra and therefor I need to ask here.

I have given a square non-symmetric Matrix $A$ and successfully decomposed it into a lower and an upper triangular matrix $L$ and $U$. To reduce numerical errors as well as ensuring that there is such a decomposition, I used pivoting.

$$P\cdot A = L \cdot U$$

The main reason I am doing this is so that I can efficiently compute the determinant as well as the inverse. Computing the determinant would be:

$$det(P) \cdot det(A) = det(L) \cdot det(U) $$
$$\rightarrow det(A) = det(U) $$

An option would be to do this:

$$A^{-1} = (P^T \cdot L \cdot U)^{-1}$$
$$A^{-1} = U^{-1} \cdot L^{-1} \cdot P$$

Computing $U^{-1}$ and $L^{-1}$ is not hard but I am afraid of the computational overhead from the multiplications. What other solution is there?

Comment: Usually, the point of doing LU decomposition is to *avoid* computing an explicit inverse, because once decomposed you can solve the system with back-propagation.

Comment: so I should potentially just use gauss to solve for the inverse instead? and compute the determinant midway

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a more reasonable approach.

Comment: correction: "back-propagation" should read "back-substitution" above

Comment: Okay I see. If you want you can post that as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, the purpose of doing LU decomposition is to avoid having to compute an inverse at all, because an upper-triangular system can be solved easily via back-substitution.

A simple way to obtain the inverse would be to just complete the Gauss-Jordan elimination the rest of the way, instead of stopping at the halfway point as one does with LU decomposition.